# Call MVC action using java script within a view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view that contain a image i want to set a button to reload this image by calling an action in my controller like this :

```
<a href="javascript://" class="Button ButtonLarge" id="Reload"><span><span class="ButtonIcon NewTopic">Refresh</span></span></a>
```

and the action like this:

```
public ActionResult Image()
        {
            var builder = new XCaptcha.ImageBuilder();
            var result = builder.Create();

            Session.Add("SecurityNumber", result.Solution);

            return new FileContentResult(result.Image, result.ContentType);
        }
```

i need to call this action using javascript and set the new image source any help will be good

Comment: you can use jquery $.get . http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ instead of using javascript

Comment: I need it to be using javascript

Comment: or if you can give me an exampl of how can i do it in jquerey

Comment: yes I am not verey good with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update an image, just update the src attribute. Using jQuery:

```
$("#Reload").click(function(e) {
    $("#Captcha").attr("src", "/path/to/your/action");

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

What this does is when you click an element with id "Reload", set the "src" attribute of the image with id "Captcha" to "/path/of/your/action". `e.preventDefault()` is there so we do not follow the link.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Reload").click(function (e) {
        $("#image").attr("src", "/AccountController/Image");

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    )};
</script>`

Comment: @Eslam Yes, that should work. Are you sure you want the Controller suffix in there? I guess it should be "/Account/Image".

Comment: thanks a lot alexn ,and i have a nother question can i made it without reloading the page

Comment: it reloads the image only one time is there is something in what i wrote